# How to listen to profile-after-change in XPCOM component for FF4

Tags: firefox, xpcom

[This blog post](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2010/06/14/multiple-breaking-changes-are-coming-for-components-in-extensions/) mentions that XPCOM components will no longer be able to observe 'app-startup' notifications and they will have to listen to 'profile-after-change' notifications now.

[My changes](http://github.com/erikvold/greasemonkey/commit/04152b48ab749f6bfead7beda0493256915d879c) don't seem to work however; any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to chrome.manifest:

```
category profile-after-change CONTRACTID CONTRACTID
```